# Facebook group/page forces me to join automatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

Why do some Facebook pages/groups just need to add me from their side and I then immediately become joined it without my review first?

Some folks add me to very dirty sites and it appears in the group I joined automatically days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because that's how Facebook have designed Facebook Groups.
See: https://www.facebook.com/help/147058305366686

It should only happen in Groups; people can't force you to "like" a page.

(If you have liked a page that you didn't actually click "like" on, then it's either caused by a misplaced click when using the mobile app/website, or else it's caused by a hacker that has created a web page that tricks you into clicking the Like button without your knowledge.)

Comment: Please give the link officially from facebook about the group policy. Thank you.

Comment: i could google it, or you could just google it yourself and save me the hassle

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/147058305366686